# I have troube with symfony fixtures

Tags: symfony

I discovered the symfony framework for a short time. and there, I'm stuck at the fixture level. I managed to create category fixtures, but I can't manage with the product fixtures. If anyone can help, that would be nice.

```
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++){
            $category = new Category();
            $category ->setName("category".$i);
            $category ->setImage("road to pic".$i);

            $manager ->persist($category);
        }
        $manager ->flush($category);

        $productRepo = $manager->getRepository(Product::class);
        $allCategory = $productRepo->findAll();
        for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= 200 ; $i++){
            $product = new Product();
            $product ->setName("product".$i);
            $product ->setImage("road to pic".$i);
            $product ->setPrice(rand(1, 100));
            $product ->setStock(rand(1,10));
            $product ->setDescription("description".$i);
            $product ->setCategory($allCategory[1]);

            $manager -> persist($product);
        }

        $manager->flush($product);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$allCategory = $productRepo->findAll();` this does not look correct.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the list of categories incorrectly in your example.

Instead of this

```
$productRepo = $manager->getRepository(Product::class);
$allCategory = $productRepo->findAll();
```

Use it

```
$allCategory =  $manager->getRepository(Category::class)->findAll();
```